# Retrofit response returning null in get method

Tags: android, retrofit

I have a url like this

```
http://182.72.198.001:8080/MyLogin/login/xxxxxx/yyyyyy

userName : xxxxxx
password : yyyyyy
```

I am using retrofit to  get the above url response but it returning null my retrofit class is

```
public class ApiClient {

    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public static Retrofit getApiCLient() {

        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://182.72.198.001:8080/MyLogin/").addConverterFactory
                    (GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

and myInterface class is

```
public interface MyInterface {

@GET("login/")
Call<ResponseBody> LoginValidation(@Query("userName") String username, @Query("password") String password);        
}
```

My main class is

```
MyInterface loginInterface;


 loginInterface = ApiClient.getApiCLient().create(MyInterface.class);
 private  void  LoginUser()
 {
     final String usedrname = username1.getText().toString();
     final String password = password1.getText().toString();
     Call<ResponseBody> call = loginInterface.LoginValidation(usedrname,password);
     Log.i("Tag","Interface" + usedrname+password);
     call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

             Log.i("Tag","Respose" + response.body());  // this body returns null
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thank You!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             editor.putString("username",usedrname);
             editor.putString("password",password);
             editor.putBoolean("isLoginKey",true);
             editor.commit();
             Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Navigation.class);
             i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
             startActivity(i);
     }
     @Override
     public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Username or password Mismatch",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         }
     });

 }
```

How can i solve this  am i did anything wrong in this code?

Answer (score 1):

http://182.72.198.001:8080/MyLogin/login/xxxxxx/yyyyyy

If you have to form the above url then you have to send the username and password in url path. So, your Retrofit interface should look like this:

```
public interface MyInterface {

    @GET("login/{userName}/{password}")
    Call<ResponseBody> LoginValidation(@Path("userName") String username, 
                                       @Path("password") String password);

}
```

Comment: I tried this also it returning this khttp3.ResponseBody$1@3febf20

Comment: if you want `response` as `json string` call `response.body().string()`

Comment: always its redirect to another page if i give a wrong username and password

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
@GET("login/")
Call<ResponseBody> LoginValidation(@Query("userName") String username, @Query("password") String password);
```

Your URL becomes: http://182.72.198.001:8080/MyLogin/login/?userName=xxxxxx&password=yyyyyy

To exact call as you need, use this (as answered by [@Avijit Karmakar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52754715/retrofit-response-returning-null-in-get-method/52754871#52754788) )

```
public interface MyInterface {

        @GET("login/{userName}/{password}")
        Call<ResponseBody> LoginValidation(@Path("userName") String username, 
                                           @Path("password") String password);

    }
```

Using this method you will get the exact result which you want.

Comment: I tried this also it returning this khttp3.ResponseBody$1@3febf20

Comment: debug you call and evaluate *call.request*. It will show you, your API request